# Communication between the web page and the native app using Chrome native messaging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to establish the communication between the web page and the native application, so that

1. The web page could send events to the native application, for example, by clicking a button
2. The native application could send events back to the web page which could be handled by JavaScript handlers

I'm trying to use Chrome Native Messaging: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

The example provided by Chrome works well (needed however some adjustment to run on Python 3.8), but that example is the **Chrome application** which doesn't seem to fit my purposes.

I changed the code so that the **Application** became the **Extension**, and the application JS script became the extension content script.

Here is the updated **manifest.json**:

```
{
  // Extension ID: knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
  "name": "Native Messaging Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

The extension starts after the webpage is loaded. To send events from the webpage to the extension, I used "Communication with the embedded page" mechanism described here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Here's the code of the extension content script **main.js**:

```
var webPort = chrome.runtime.connect();
var nativePort = null;

function sendNativeMessage(text) {
  message = {"text": text};
  nativePort.postMessage(message);
}

function onNativeMessage(message) {
    webPort.postMessage({"type": "response", "text": message.text});
}

function onDisconnected() {
    webPort.postMessage({"type": "connect-error", "text": chrome.runtime.lastError.message});
    nativePort = null;
}

function connect() {
  var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
  nativePort = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  nativePort.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
  nativePort.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
}

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window || !event.data.type) {
        return;
    }

    console.log("Content script received message, type: " + event.data.type);
    if (event.data.type === "connect") {
        connect();
    } else if (event.data.type === "send") {
        sendNativeMessage(event.data.text);
    }
}, false);
```

But, when I'm opening the web page, I'm getting two issues.

1. The code `chrome.runtime.connect()` raises an error:

   **Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.**
2. The code `chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName)` raises an error:

   **Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function.**

What I am doing wrong?

The full code of the test project is here: https://github.com/h-mdm/test-chrome-ext

Subdirectories **app** and **host** contain a working example by Chrome. Subdirectories **ext** and **web** contain the extension example which is raising errors.

Comment: connect() needs a background script to connect to ([info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)), connectNative() can be used only in that background script. So, your workflow will be web page -> content script -> background script -> native host.

Comment: Thank you, will try this. Can a web page communicate directly with a background script without content script?

Comment: Yes, but it won't work with `<all_urls>`, see "Sending messages from web pages" in the link I gave.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it working (but on website only, localhost and local drive are not supported!). The final code is here: https://github.com/h-mdm/test-chrome-ext  Please arrange your comment as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @vmayorow, are localhost and local drive not supported because of security restrictions, or is it part of your implementation?

Comment: @vmayorow I think I understand, the externally_connectable property in the manifest.json file requires a second level domain, and does not allow 'localhost'.

Comment: @ChrisKennedy you are right, localhost doesn't work, not sure why. I simulated a second level domain by adding it to the hosts file.